# Xcode - Is it possible to view Main.storyboard in the Interface Builder and its source code simultaneously?

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode8, uistoryboard

I can open either the Source Code or Interface Builder view of the Storyboard individually.

I'd really like to open both side-by-side, as I found certain features maddeningly missing from the Interface Builder UI, like adding constraints between arbitrary attributes; e.g., the trailing side of a label to the view center.

I can't get Xcode to do this via the Assistant editor. It seems like the most useful development Storyboard display, as then I could edit the code by hand when necessary and immediately see the result, or quickly look up data I need (such as the component IDs) for the source code.

Comment: You mean accessing and modifying the interface builder file directly (somewhat like for Android) ? Then no, you can't. It's an xml file so you could probably understand it, but you would probably break it as well.

Comment: Storyboard is XML file essentially, you actually could open it with external Editor.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the Assistant editor there is a square divided into four on the upper left side of the split screen, which allows you to manually pick what goes on that side of the screen.

Comment: just started to use the XCode on the 1st day, where is the Assistant editor??